# Can I re-encounter a pokemon that ran away from me?

Tags: pokemon-go

I had a high level pokemon run away from me when I tried to catch it. Is it possible to re-encounter it in the same place?

If so, how long do I have to wait until I'm able to find it again?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, if a Pokémon escapes you can't find that Pokémon ever again with your account. You may, however, find another one of the same species, but there is no telling about time and location.

However, if *you* escape from the "fight" you will see the Pokémon again right where you found it (unless the spawn timer has expired).

Comment: Note that "escaping" sometimes includes the case where you throw a Pokeball, the servers go kaput, and you reload. If the Pokemon doesn't show up in your journal, you can encounter it again.

Comment: ^ Assuming, of course, that it hasn't despawned in that time - a likely possibility depending on how long it takes to reload the game.

Comment: in addition: It is possible to get the egg for (and hatch) the escaped Pokémon.

Comment: Nope. It's just the same species, but not the very same Pokémon you lost.